# How can I connect my flutter project to postgresql database? (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: postgresql, flutter

I tried using flutter dependency "postgres" but my connection is refused. I also don't know how to start my postgresql server on ubuntu or call it using a restapi.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should also know that Postgres is a database and serves no RESTful API directly. You will likely need an additional service that works with your database and serves an API for your flutter application.

Answer (score 0):

Hay ,, you want to connect flutter app to postgresql right?
Firstly you can't use flutter in web mod to postgresql

1-> Create a user in postgresql, something like username flutter password flutter,   give permission for that user to read the table. easy commands
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO flutter;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO flutter;

2-> Configure your postgresql database for created user (eg.flutter)
https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-a-remote-postgres-database-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/    check that link to configure postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf
after that test connect by psql command ->psql -h (host) -d (database) -U (user)
host    databasename flutter  0.0.0.0/0     md5  inhba
listen_addresses = '*'   inconfig

3->  Add fire wall rule,,
for windows
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="postgresin" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8069
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="postgresout" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8069

4->https://pub.dev/packages/postgres try